# Sending a stream of screen captures in C++

Tags: c++, bitmap, stream, screenshot

I'm looking for a way to convert a screen capture to a char* in an efficient way.
I thought about capturing the screen using a bitmap object, then converting the bitmap object to an array of bytes and then to a char*, but I couldn't find any way to convert then bitmap to an array of bytes.
I also thought about iterating every pixel in the screen capture and saving the RGB values in an array, but that creates an array that is too big for me.

The end goal is to return a char* object in the fastest way that doesn't return an object that is too large, and that char* contains the data of the screen captured.

Comment: How about just `reinterpret_cast<char*>(pointer_to_raw_screenshot_data)`?

Comment: "...I couldn't find any way to convert the bitmap to an array of bytes" - you should search a little harder, because that is pretty much all a bitmap is eventually.

Answer (score 0):

You don't given enough info/code to understand what you're really trying to achieve by this. E.g. how are you planning to represent the colour coefficients?  Anyway, a way to go would be to use the opencv library, e.g.:

```
  cv::Mat mat = cv::imread("PATH/TO/YOUR/FILE.bmp");

  char table[mat.rows * mat.cols * 3]; // assuming that we have 3 colour channels
  unsigned int index = 0;

  cv::MatIterator_<uchar> it, end; 
  for( it = mat.begin<uchar>(), end = mat.end<uchar>(); it != end; ++it) 
    table[index++] = *it;
```